# VueJS computed property does not update

Tags: vue.js

I have a computed property:

```
outputData() {
        if(this.yearSelected) {
            let res = this.taikoData
                        .map(item => {
                            return {
                                showName: item.showName,
                                IdMitgliedschaftenPersonen: item.IdMitgliedschaftenPersonen,
                                PaidProp: item.paidDate
                                                    .filter(item => item.paidDate.substr(0,4)==this.yearSelected)
                                                    .sort((a,b) => (a.paidDate>b.paidDate) ? 1 :( (b.paidDate>a.paidDate) ? -1 : 0 )),
                             }   
                        })
        return res
        } 
        else {
            return []
        }
}
```

It receives data from the taikoData object (populated during mounting) and filters it to match the current year. Then I can add a month for which a member is absent and does not have to pay the monthly subscription fee.

[image: screenshot of user interface]

The screenshot shows the user interface. When clicking the button, I add the month and through an event update the taikoData-object. The data is also being saved in a database. I would like to see the updated data immediately inside the data table. However, it doesn't update. Only when changing the yearSelected-filter back and forth the updated data will show (or of course when refreshing the page).

What I have tried so far:

1) this.$forceUpdate() inside a function of the method-prop when receiving the $emit-data. It didn't work

2) extend the condition with a counter-variable which initially equals 0: if(this.yearSelected || counter > 0). The counter will increase each time when emitting the data back to the parent.

The data table is a vuetify datatable:

```
<v-data-table
                    :items="outputData"
                    :headers="headers"
                    :search="search"
                    sort-by="showName"
                     :footer-props="{
                        'items-per-page-options': [20,50,75,-1],
                     }"
                >
```

The taikoData is initially retrieved here:

```
async mounted()
    {
        let res = await api.get("https://requestURL")
        res = res.data.records
        this.taikoData = res
}
```

Comment: 1. Is `taikoData` defined as a `data` property? 2. Could you post the code you use to populate and update it?

Comment: Oh boy. I was seriously searching for 3 hours... And no, it wasn't... And yes, it works after assigning it to be a data prop....